# DateTime localization issue with timeago

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, localization

I am outputting a date in GB format to my browser: `01/06/2012 15:50:01 -03:00` (1 June , 2012)

This is done on the server in C# with `DateTimeOffset.ToString()`

I would like to use jQuery.timeago on this date. Everything works fine, except for one problem: jQuery.timeago parses the above date as `01/06/2012 15:50:01 -03:00` (Jan 6, 2012)

One solution is to just do a `DateTimeOffset.ToString(formatStringHere)`, but this needs to work locale-agnostically, so I'm not sure if that solution would work.

Comment: Is it possible to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335841.aspx to get a string that jQuery.timeago will recognise?

Comment: jQuery.timeago uses javascript's new Date()

Comment: If you're going to use timeago on it, why do you output the date in this format ? You could simply output it in the timeago expected format ... Otherwise you could hide the date in the correct format in a data attribute, jQuery access it and manipulate it with timeago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely on the parameterless `DateTimeOffset.ToString()` method to be culture-agnostic. I would suggest using the round-trip format specifier (`"O"` or `"o"`) to format your date unambiguously per the ISO 8601 standard (such that it will be parsed correctly under all cultures) whilst preserving timezone information.

From MSDN:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0);
DateTimeOffset dateOffset = new DateTimeOffset(date1, 
    TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(date1));
Console.WriteLine(dateOffset.ToString("o"));
// Displays 2008-04-10T06:30:00.0000000-07:00
```

The [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) website appears to indicate that it supports ISO 8601.

**Edit**: The `"o"` format specifier is equivalent to the following custom format string:

```
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffzzz"
```

If you want to limit your precision to milliseconds, you could adjust it so:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0);
DateTimeOffset dateOffset = new DateTimeOffset(date1, new TimeSpan(-7, 0, 0));
Console.WriteLine(dateOffset.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffzzz"));
// Displays 2008-04-10T06:30:00.000-07:00
```

Comment: This would be the best solution if timeago didn't have some strange regex parsing of the date.

I ended up calculating it to milliseconds and writing my own Parse() method in timeago. Thanks for this though

Answer (score 0):

Use ISO-8601 standard: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ to communicate datetime in C# and Jquery. 
Means use two values one for display and one JQuery.